# iOS App Submission without @3x images and build with xcode 6.1

Tags: ios

I am planning to submit an iOS app to appstore. I developed this App earlier with xcode5.1 which supports iOS 6.0 and later(iOS8 was not released that time).

Do I want to restructure my app for ios 8.0 by including launch screen and icon images for iphone 6 and 6 plus.? (When I add @3x launch images for iPhone6/6 plus its showing some alignment issues with my screens which will force me to postpone my release.)

Will my app get rejected if I build the App with xcode 6.1 without including launch screen and icon images for iphone 6 and 6 plus.?

Answer (score 0):

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) says :

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6 Plus, at least one 5.5-inch screenshot is required. Up to four additional screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the screenshots when you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.

There is a similar message for iPhone 6.

The question is now how to you indicate your app support iPhone 6/6 Plus ? iPhone 5  support was indicated when a  4" launch image was added to your project, so i guess iPhone 6/6 Plus support will only be added when the according launch images will be added to your project.

Xcode 6 also allows the use of a Launch screen file instead of Launch images. If you choose this option, iPhone 6/6 plus support will automatically be added since the Launch Screen handles all available the sizes.

**To answer your question** : your app should be accepted without the launch screen because it indicates you doesn't support iPhone 6/6 plus. Try to add these resolution when you can, Apple added [some constraints](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) about distribution, starting February 1, 2015, and maybe they'll do the same for resolution.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. If I want to include iPhone6/6+ screen layout support in less time, Can I create separate xib files for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus Will it be a good idea or is there any better solution?

Comment: If you want to support multiple screen sizes, the best way is  using Autolayout, available since iOS 6 and Xcode 4. Xcode 6 also provides 'size classes' which allows you to customize even more your view for differents devices, but is compatible only from iOS 7. There are great WWDC videos about these themes.